# Crear nuevo archivo cada que se ejecuta el comando xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con SQL y lo que quiero es que cada que ejecuto el comando `xp_cmdshell` se genere un nuevo archivo, ya que como lo tengo actualmente sobre escribe el mismo, les dejo el código de mi *query*:

```
DECLARE @Comando VARCHAR(2048) 
SET @Comando = 'bcp "Select * FROM DataBase.dbo.Table" '
+ 'queryout "C:\SAP\Prueba.txt" '
+ '-S "WIN-7A84OQD1HG6\SQLEXPRESS" '
+ '-U "sa" -P "123" -c' 
EXEC xp_cmdshell @Comando;
```

Comment: Al sobre escribir el archivo se estaría generando uno nuevo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cambia esta línea:

```
+ 'queryout "C:\SAP\Prueba.txt" '
```

Por esta:

```
+ 'queryout "C:\SAP\Prueba ' + Convert(VARCHAR(50),NEWID()) + '.txt" '
```

De esta manera siempre vas a tener un nombre de archivo diferente ya que `NewId()` es una función de TSql que retorna un identificador único (`uniqueidentifier`), éste a su vez debes convertirlo a `VARCHAR` para poderlo concatenar con el nombre del archivo.

Si quieres testear el funcionamiento prueba esto multiples veces en tu SQL Server Management Studio:

```
PRINT '"C:\SAP\Prueba ' + Convert(VARCHAR(50),NEWID()) + '.txt"'
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql

Comment: podrias explicar porque esta solucion es buena para la pregunta?

Comment: @gbianchi Porque le esta asignando un identificador a txt para siempre crear uno nuevo y que no se sobre escriban

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti se lo que esta haciendo, estoy pidiendo que mejore la respuesta explicandola un poco (sobre todo que hace NEWID) porque la misma fue reportada como de baja caliad..

Comment: @PistcheLawliet me parece correcta esta respuesta, aunque se me ocurre que en lugar de un nuevo identificador único, se concatene la fecha y la hora en formato `YYYMMDD_HHmmSS`, intenta con [`SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 114), ':','')`](http://rextester.com/OGP59551). Con esto, será más fácil identicar el archivo.

Comment: De acuerdo, la idea era ilustrar que lo que se debia hacer era cambiar el nombre del archivo mediante algum metodo cada vez que se llame el procedimiento.

Comment: @Flxtr gracias, era gusto lo que necesitaba, Saludos!